# why is this dynamic programming answer slow?

Tags: ruby, dynamic-programming

Why is this solution slow? I'm guessing it's because the sub-problems are not solved at the right time when they should be. What am I doing wrong?

```
 def longest_palindrome(s)
    len = s.length
    longest_start = 0
    longest_end = 0
    mem = Array.new(len) { Array.new(len, -1) }
    
    (0..(len - 1)).each do |i|
        (i..(len - 1)).each do |j|
            if util(i, j, s, mem) && j - i > longest_end - longest_start
                longest_start = i
                longest_end = j
            end
        end
    end
    s[longest_start..longest_end]
end

def util(i, j, s, mem)
    return mem[i][j] if mem[i][j] != -1
    judge = s[i] == s[j]           
    mem[i][j] = j - i >= 2 ? util(i+1, j-1, s, mem) && judge : judge  
end
```

Comment: For a string of length _n_, you run about _n*n_ times the function `util`, which in turn is a recursive function. I would expect the program to be very busy when checking long palindromes, but be faster for very short palindromes or words where the first and last character differ.

Comment: I also don't see how your algorithm is related to _dynamic programming_....

Comment: @user1934428 I am building up the solution from subproblems and memoizing the answers. that is basically DP, right? util is a fast return if it finds the answer to an already computed subproblem.

Comment: @user1934428 Interestingly, the long palindrome runs a bit faster; QED in my answer.

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed : I don't see how momoizing is related to [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), but using recursivity, as you do, might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call your solution slow, although of course that is an entirely arbitrary characterization.

That said, I thought I might test user1934428's expectation a bit, and see whether your code is indeed faster for very short palindromes, while further testing your code against a simpler solution that just loops around `#each_cons` and uses `#reverse` to check for palindromes.

Here's the method I came up with:

```
def longest_palindrome2(str)
  longest = str.size
  loop do
    str.chars.each_cons(longest) do |substr|
      return substr.join if substr == substr.reverse || longest == 1
    end
    longest -= 1
  end
end
```

I tested both your and my solution with two fairly long strings, one with a very short palindrome (`x` with a longest palindrome of three characters) and one with quite a long one (`y`, where the longest palindrome is the entire 125-character string):

```
x = 'alkneowinlsoirneleibesemssooeineiiqkwjviowrsitheixwlelajsdk awjlk;ja ;kja ;lk jasdkj a;lskdja pwoeiarjpowiecjpnaowiejcnpaosijcrnpoeirjn'

t = Time.now()
10.times { longest_palindrome(x) }
p Time.now() - t
t = Time.now()
10.times { longest_palindrome2(x) }
p Time.now() - t

y = 'satorarepotenetoperarotassatorarepotenetoperarotassatorarepotenetoperarotassatorarepotenetoperarotassatorarepotenetoperarotas'

t = Time.now()
10.times { longest_palindrome(y) }
p Time.now() - t
t = Time.now()
10.times { longest_palindrome2(y) }
p Time.now() - t
```

I got these results:

```
0.109101
0.266618
0.094408
0.000618
```

As it turns out, yours is a bit faster with the long palindrome, while mine is a great deal faster. Further, yours is significantly faster than mine with the short palindrome, while mine is significantly faster than yours with the long palindrome.

So, mine varies a great deal depending on how long the palindrome is (which makes sense, because the number of iterations it has to do increases very rapidly as the size of the longest palindrome decreases). Yours performs much more consistently than mine as the size of the result varies.

In other words, whether I would call your solution slow depends on how long the longest palindrome is relative to the size of the input string.

Comment: th anks for that explanation! also, that Ruby code is dope. #TIL `each_cons`

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed You're most welcome. I thought `#each_cons` was "dope," too, when I first ran across it. Except at my somewhat advanced age I actually thought it was "way cool, man." :)

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed` I did a bit of tinkering and added some more info at the end of this post.

Comment: I don't think that works. we don't want to return as soon as the next longest palindrome is found. we want to go through all iterations and return the longest palindrome at the end

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed I tried several different strings and they appeared to work correctly. The point is that if you start with the entire string, and then keep looking at progressively shorter strings until you find a palindrome, you have found the longest one and don't need to keep looking. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think if the string has multiple palindrome substrings, your solution won't work. a simple example is "bb". The answer we get with your solution is "b", but the actual answer is "bb".

Comment: @AmirShadaabMohammed You're right. I must have tried strings that didn't have that flaw. `'abbccddd'` comes back `'bb'` as well. Ok, I'm going to delete that part of my post. Thanks for checking it — more carefully than I did!